# OpenCV 3.0, Why I can't compute HoG with cell size = size(5,5)?

Tags: opencv3.0, visual-c++-2013

I program on visual c++ 2013 configured with OpenCV 3.0.

I try to compute HoG descriptor for images reseized to 40x40 pixels.

My following code works right with default parameters :

```
hog.cellSize = cv::Size(8, 8);
hog.blockSize = cv::Size(16, 16);
hog.blockStride = cv::Size(8, 8);
hog.nbins = 9;
winStride = cv::Size(8, 8);
```

but with different parameters it doesn't work :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
HOGDescriptor hog; // Use standard parameters here

hog.winSize = cv::Size(40, 40); // Default training images size as used in paper
cv::Size trainingPadding = cv::Size(0, 0);


// specific parameters
hog.cellSize = cv::Size(5, 5);
hog.blockSize = cv::Size(10, 10);
hog.blockStride = cv::Size(5, 5);
hog.nbins = 8;
cv::Size winStride = cv::Size(5, 5);

// default parameters
/*hog.cellSize = cv::Size(8, 8);
hog.blockSize = cv::Size(16, 16);
hog.blockStride = cv::Size(8, 8);
hog.nbins = 9;
cv::Size winStride = cv::Size(8, 8);*/

vector<float> featureVector;
Mat imageDataRaw = imread("../image1.ppm", 0);// read an image
Mat imageData;
resize(imageDataRaw, imageData, hog.winSize);
// Check for mismatching dimensions
if (imageData.cols != hog.winSize.width || imageData.rows != hog.winSize.height) {
    featureVector.clear();
    printf("Error: Image '%s' dimensions (%u x %u) do not match HOG window size (%u x %u)!\n", "image1.ppm", imageData.cols, imageData.rows, hog.winSize.width, hog.winSize.height);
    return -1;
}
vector<Point> locations;

hog.compute(imageData, featureVector, winStride, trainingPadding, locations);

return 0;
}
```

and I have an SEHException:

[SEHException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mylg.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At least on [OpenCV till 2.4.12 ](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor-hogdescriptor) only the default values were supported. However, it seems that this limitation is gone in OpenCV 3.0. Can you please post a working example?

Comment: No, I mean a self contained code snippet I can copy & paste & run ([mcve]). We don't always have the time to complete the missing part of the snippet you provided. If you can post it, it will save us a lot of time, and  you'll get an answer sooner.

Comment: In simple words, can you post the _main_ function?

Comment: Here we go... thanks :D

Comment: OK. There are a lot of constraints on the mutual sizes of this variables. This makes non-trivial to arbitrarily change them. You'd better stuck with default parameters.

Comment: I did not change these parameters arbitrary but according to the hog approach.

Comment: I'm not saying you chose some random values, but that OpenCV implementation is based on strict mutual relations among this parameters. So there's nothing more I can do for you. Let's hope that someone else has a good answer for you. Good luck!

Comment: Really strange, i just tried you code on linux and it works perfectly (it doesn't crash, at least). From what i see, there aren't many constraints on sizes in opencv3.0, and your code respect them all... Are you sure you are using the 3.0 version? You don't have multiple opencv versions installed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I use the 3.0 version. It is really strange beacause  with another specific parameters it works perfectly but with the parameters specified below is not working !!